# Need a more "DRY" solution for my CircleCI tests

Tags: node.js, testing, circleci, code-climate

Currently I have a working circleci yaml file but it runs a separate test script for each app. It's not "DRY" and I think a better solution would be to run the test script from the root and loop over each app...but I can't figure out how to do that. I've seen some examples but anytime I try to apply them, circle can't seem to find the clover files so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I'd LOVE to run everything in parallel too but my first need is to just eliminate all the extra steps.

This is the current setup:

file system structure:

```
- apps
  - **app1**
    - coverage
      - clover.xml
      - coverage-final.json
    - src
      - test-files
    package.json
  - **app2**
    - coverage
      - clover.xml
      - coverage-final.json
    - src
      - test-files
    package.json
  - **app3**
    - coverage
      - clover.xml
      - coverage-final.json
    - src
      - test-files
    package.json
- package.json
```

root/package.json scripts

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "lerna run lint --concurrency=2",
    "build": "lerna run build --concurrency=1 --stream",
    "bootstrap:ci": "lerna bootstrap --ci --concurrency=2"
    "test": "CI=true lerna run test:coverage --concurrency=2 --stream -- --coverage",
    "test:app1": "cd apps/enhanced-date-editor && npm run test:coverage",
    "test:app2": "cd apps/input-fields-group && npm run test:coverage",
    "test:app3": "cd apps/markdown-items-list && npm run test:coverage",
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "lerna": "^3.22.1"
  }
}
```

app[1/2/3]/package.json scripts

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "test:coverage": "npm t -- --coverage",
    "deploy": "s3 bucket script",
  },
  "jest": {
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "**/*.{js,jsx,tsx}",
      "!**/node_modules/**",
      "!**/vendor/**"
    ]
  }
}
```

circleci/config.yml

```
version: 2.1
executors:
  node:
    docker:
      - image: cimg/node:14.15.4

jobs:
  prepare:
    executor: node
    steps:
      - checkout
      - run:
          name: Install dependencies
          command: |
            npm i
            npm run bootstrap:ci
      - persist_to_workspace:
          root: .
          paths:
            - .

  lint:
    executor: node
    steps:
      - attach_workspace:
          at: .
      - run:
          name: lint
          command: npm run lint
  test-reporter:
    executor: node
    steps:
      - run:
          name: Setup Code Climate test-reporter
          command: |
            # download test reporter as a static binary
            mkdir -p testing-workspace/test-results/coverage
            curl -L https://codeclimate.com/downloads/test-reporter/test-reporter-latest-linux-amd64 > testing-workspace/cc-test-reporter
            chmod +x testing-workspace/cc-test-reporter
      - persist_to_workspace:
          root: testing-workspace
          paths:
            - cc-test-reporter
  test-app1:
    executor: node
    steps:
      - attach_workspace:
          at: .
      - attach_workspace:
          at: ~/project/testing-workspace
      - run:
          name: Testing and formatting for codeclimate
          command: |
            testing-workspace/cc-test-reporter before-build
            npm run test:app1
            testing-workspace/cc-test-reporter format-coverage \
              "apps/app1/coverage/clover.xml" \
              --input-type clover \
              --output testing-workspace/test-results/coverage/coverage.app1.json
      - persist_to_workspace:
          root: testing-workspace
          paths:
            - test-results/coverage/coverage.app1.json
  test-app2:
    executor: node
    steps:
      - attach_workspace:
          at: .
      - attach_workspace:
          at: ~/project/testing-workspace
      - run:
          name: Testing and formatting for codeclimate
          command: |
            testing-workspace/cc-test-reporter before-build
            npm run test:app2
            testing-workspace/cc-test-reporter format-coverage \
              "apps/app2/coverage/clover.xml" \
              --input-type clover \
              --output testing-workspace/test-results/coverage/coverage.app2.json
      - persist_to_workspace:
          root: testing-workspace
          paths:
            - test-results/coverage/coverage.app2.json
  test-app3:
    executor: node
    steps:
      - attach_workspace:
          at: .
      - attach_workspace:
          at: ~/project/testing-workspace
      - run:
          name: Testing and formatting for codeclimate
          command: |
            testing-workspace/cc-test-reporter before-build
            npm run test:app3
            testing-workspace/cc-test-reporter format-coverage \
              "apps/app3/coverage/clover.xml" \
              --input-type clover \
              --output testing-workspace/test-results/coverage/coverage.app3.json
      - persist_to_workspace:
          root: testing-workspace
          paths:
            - test-results/coverage/coverage.app3.json
  ship-all-the-test-results:
    executor: node
    steps:
      - attach_workspace:
          at: ~/project/testing-workspace
      - run:
          name: sum coverage
          command: testing-workspace/cc-test-reporter sum-coverage -o testing-workspace/test-results/coverage/coverage.total.json testing-workspace/test-results/coverage/coverage.*.json;
      - run:
          name: ship results to code climate
          command: testing-workspace/cc-test-reporter upload-coverage --input testing-workspace/test-results/coverage/coverage.total.json
      - store_artifacts:
          path: testing-workspace/test-results
          destination: test-results
      - store_test_results:
          path: testing-workspace/test-results
workflows:
  build-test-deploy:
    jobs:
      - prepare
      - lint:
          requires:
            - prepare
      - test-reporter:
          requires:
            - lint
      - test-app1:
          requires:
            - test-reporter
      - test-app2:
          requires:
            - test-reporter
      - test-app3:
          requires:
            - test-reporter
      - ship-all-the-test-results:
          requires:
            - test-app1
            - test-app2
            - test-app3
```

Example of what I've tried

```
testing-workspace/cc-test-reporter before-build
npm run test
testing-workspace/cc-test-reporter format-coverage apps/**/coverage/clover.xml --input-type clover --output apps/**/coverage/coverage-final.json
testing-workspace/cc-test-reporter sum-coverage apps/**/coverage/coverage-final.json --output testing-workspace/test-results/coverage/codeclimate.total.json
testing-workspace/cc-test-reporter upload-coverage --input testing-workspace/test-results/coverage/coverage.total.json
testing-workspace/cc-test-reporter after-build --exit-code $?
```

error was  `git head does not match`

Another Example of what I have tried

```
#!/bin/bash -eo pipefail
# notify codeclimate that a build is coming
testing-workspace/cc-test-reporter before-build
# run tests
# will receive a list of test files and the CircleCI CLI will split them by timing data.
TESTFILES=$(circleci tests glob "apps/**.js" | circleci tests split)
npm run test ${TESTFILES}
# format test results
testing-workspace/cc-test-reporter format-coverage "**/**/clover.xml" --input-type clover --output "apps/**/coverage/coverage-final.json"
# combine test results
testing-workspace/cc-test-reporter sum-coverage -o testing-workspace/test-results/coverage/coverage.total.json "apps/**/coverage/coverage-final.json"
# upload test results to codeclimate
testing-workspace/cc-test-reporter upload-coverage --input testing-workspace/test-results/coverage/coverage.total.json
# notify codeclimate that build is completed
testing-workspace/cc-test-reporter after-build --exit-code $?
```

error was ```could not find coverage file **/**/clover.xml
could not find any files in search paths for clover. search paths were: **/**/clover.xml, build/logs/clover.xml, clover.xml ``

Answer (score 0):

There is no loop in CircleCI config syntax, but you can make the config more DRY by adding a parameter for the app to your test-app job.

```
version: 2.1
executors:
  node:
    docker:
      - image: cimg/node:14.15.4

jobs:
  prepare:
    executor: node
    steps:
      - checkout
      - run:
          name: Install dependencies
          command: |
            npm i
            npm run bootstrap:ci
      - persist_to_workspace:
          root: .
          paths:
            - .

  lint:
    executor: node
    steps:
      - attach_workspace:
          at: .
      - run:
          name: lint
          command: npm run lint
  test-reporter:
    executor: node
    steps:
      - run:
          name: Setup Code Climate test-reporter
          command: |
            # download test reporter as a static binary
            mkdir -p testing-workspace/test-results/coverage
            curl -L https://codeclimate.com/downloads/test-reporter/test-reporter-latest-linux-amd64 > testing-workspace/cc-test-reporter
            chmod +x testing-workspace/cc-test-reporter
      - persist_to_workspace:
          root: testing-workspace
          paths:
            - cc-test-reporter
  test-app:
    executor: node
    parameters:
      app_name:
        type: string
    steps:
      - attach_workspace:
          at: .
      - attach_workspace:
          at: ~/project/testing-workspace
      - run:
          name: Testing and formatting for codeclimate
          command: |
            testing-workspace/cc-test-reporter before-build
            npm run test:<< parameters.app_name >>
            testing-workspace/cc-test-reporter format-coverage \
              "apps/<< parameters.app_name >>/coverage/clover.xml" \
              --input-type clover \
              --output testing-workspace/test-results/coverage/coverage.<< parameters.app_name >>.json
      - persist_to_workspace:
          root: testing-workspace
          paths:
            - test-results/coverage/coverage.<< parameters.app_name >>.json
  ship-all-the-test-results:
    executor: node
    steps:
      - attach_workspace:
          at: ~/project/testing-workspace
      - run:
          name: sum coverage
          command: testing-workspace/cc-test-reporter sum-coverage -o testing-workspace/test-results/coverage/coverage.total.json testing-workspace/test-results/coverage/coverage.*.json;
      - run:
          name: ship results to code climate
          command: testing-workspace/cc-test-reporter upload-coverage --input testing-workspace/test-results/coverage/coverage.total.json
      - store_artifacts:
          path: testing-workspace/test-results
          destination: test-results
      - store_test_results:
          path: testing-workspace/test-results
workflows:
  build-test-deploy:
    jobs:
      - prepare
      - lint:
          requires:
            - prepare
      - test-reporter:
          requires:
            - lint
      - test-app:
          name: test-app1
          app_name: app1
          requires:
            - test-reporter
      - test-app:
          name: test-app2
          app_name: app2
          requires:
            - test-reporter
      - test-app:
          name: test-app3
          app_name: app3
          requires:
            - test-reporter
      - ship-all-the-test-results:
          requires:
            - test-app1
            - test-app2
            - test-app3
```